# How to change the port number of the gulp-angular project when using loopback REST API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loopbackjs

I´m making a project using loopback on the backend and angular on my frontend. The client side was generated with gulp-angular. After that I added the lb-services.js from loopback. The problem I´m having is that the angular app is trying to make requests to the API on the same port I have the `gulp serve running`. I have my loopback app on port 3000 and Angular runs on port 3001.

How can I tell Angular to change the port number when making request to the API?

I´ve tried modifying the gulp `server.js` like this:

```
  browserSync.instance = browserSync.init({
    startPath: '/',
    server: server,
    browser: browser,
    port:4000
  });
```

But this just makes both angular and the requests it makes on the API run on port 4000, getting me this result:

Angular running on:
`http://localhost:4000/`

Request to loopback server:

```
http://localhost:4000/api/People
```

What I want is this:
Angular running on:
`http://localhost:4000/`

Request to loopback server:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/People
```

Can anyone help me achive this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a rewriteRule for the API to change the URL to localhost:3000. As shown here:
https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-rewriteRules

Another option that's available for you is this: https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular/blob/master/docs/how-it-works.md#proxy.
You can use a proxy to redirect the API request to the correct URL. Like this (taken from Github example):

```
app.use('/api', proxy({target: 'http://localhost:3000/api', changeOrigin: true}));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Can you tell me where specifically do I have to put the proxy code in order for it to work? is it on the server side or on the client side? And which file should I search for to put the code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I´ve added this code on gulp/server.js:   `server.middleware = proxyMiddleware('/api', {
     target: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
     changeOrigin: true

   });`
However I´m still getting the request sended to port 4000

Comment: I'm not sure on this, but maybe this link can be useful for you: https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-serveStatic that has some more information in it about how you could possibly do it.